# GCP Dataflow streaming data to BigQuery RAW table, trigger transformation/insertion into data mart table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm using Dataflow(apache beam) to stream data from PubSub to BigQuery. As I'm using BigQuery streaming inserts there are no audit logs that I can use to trigger additional transformations and insertion into the final destination in a data mart table. What method can be used to continuously transform and insert the data from raw -> mart, as the data is being streamed into the raw table?
I do not want to make the transoformation/insertion with Bigquery Scheduled Queries, if there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1 :**

You can apply a design with full streaming pipelines :

```
TOPIC RAW -> Dataflow job Sink RAW data to Bigquery (RAW table)
          -> Dataflow job applying transformations and sink data to the Datamart
```

In this case there are 2 subscribers that are the 2 `Dataflow` jobs

Each `Dataflow` job will have a clear responsability and to apply the expected business transformations and sink.

**Solution 2 :**

You can also use a `Cloud Run` or `Cloud Function` action on a `BigQuery` event with [Eventarc](https://lakshmanok.medium.com/how-to-trigger-cloud-run-actions-on-bigquery-events-e818ee910560)

This solution is interesting if you really want to synchronise your data after the insertion on the first table.

Example :

```bash
gcloud eventarc triggers create ${SERVICE}-trigger \
  --location ${REGION} --service-account ${SVC_ACCOUNT} \
  --destination-run-service ${SERVICE}  \
  --event-filters type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written \
  --event-filters methodName=google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob \
  --event-filters serviceName=bigquery.googleapis.com
```

Comment: How will the second dataflow job from RAW -> Datamart retrieve the data
/ get triggered to stream data?

Comment: It’s triggered in real time with a Pub Sub subscription on the topic. Dataflow can read data in real time from a Pub Sub subscription

Comment: Okey so the pubsub topic should be connected to the raw table somehow ?

Comment: The entry point for the two Dataflow job is your raw topic. Then the Dataflow will read data in real time from this topic

Comment: Ah okey, the my intention was to stream data from the RAW Table in BigQuery to the mart table in BigQuery. Not from PubSub topic to both the raw table and the mart table

Comment: I also proposed another direction with an eventarc event that can trigger an action after inserting data on the `BigQuery` raw table.

Comment: When using BigQuery streaming inserts there are no audit logs. Can eventarc be used without the audit logs when inserting data to BigQuery?

Comment: Or am I wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure for Streaming insert. I think for Streaming insert, the solution with Pub Sub en full real time is more adapted.

Comment: Note that you can have a single Dataflow pipeline that reads from PubSub and writes to two distinct sinks. You could also use the https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html transform to delay the writes for the second sink until after the BigQuery writes have been completed.

Comment: Is the cloud functions approach cost-efficient? I

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are considering transforming the data in bigquery I think you can remove the dataflow component since you can insert from pub/sub into bigquery directly.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery

Second, you have two options to transform the data:

- Scheduled queries
- Views

Depending on the complexity of the transformations, you can rely on views to offer a curated view of the raw data with immediate access to fresh data.

A usual approach to this scenario is to leverage both mechanisms so that:

- views allow the consumption of fresh data, with a performance penalty (transformations are executed on the fly)
- scheduled queries consolidate data on a regular basis, to execute the transformations and store the final data.

So you can UNION the consolidated data with the fresh data to build a view and execute scheduled queries to transform and store the raw data in the consolidated dataset.

This approach will isolate the consumers from the underlying hybrid model.

Comment: We are using dataflow for the first step to the raw table as we are doing some initial transformation / adding some data

Comment: ok, it makes sense then to add the component to the technical design.

Comment: Doing a direct PubSub to BigQuery connection make sense if there isn't any transformation. If you want to inject logic between what is consumed from PubSub and what gets inserted into BigTable, Dataflow is a good tool to do this with.